# Unity2D 5 - Flickering sprites on Android

Tags: unity, 2d, android, screen, bug

So the game had been working fine for a few days on Android phone without any issues. Today, after adding some scripts and tweaking the game a little bit (tweaks which have nothing to do with the sprites and the issue itself), the game assets/sprites started on flicker. On PC, they looked fine, but once ported to Android as a developer build, they started to flicker constantly, even after restart.

I decided to go in Player Settings and played with some check marks but nothing seemed to help.

Following are my current Player Settings :

[image: Resolution and Presentation]
[image: Other Settings]

Any help would be appreciated.

Oh also, I have GUI in my game, can it be the problem?

Comment: Revert the changes you made and see if that fixes it. If it does, review your changes more carefully for anything that might be affecting the rendering.

Comment: Sometimes flickering is due to sprites all being on the same z level. E.g. the background and player are on the same z level so the renderer doesn't know which to draw.

Comment: @Daniel All Sprites are on Z level 0 but I have separated them with layers. They had been like that even before I made the changes.

Comment: @Byte56 I will try it

Comment: @Byte56 I tried reverting everything but the problem still persists. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Daniel Nope, changing Z level doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time "Generate Mip Map" is the core reason behind such problems. Please switch off this option for all sprite import setting. This option is only needed for 3D objects where the engine can scale down the texture according to the z distance for performance optimization.

You can read more about Mip Maps in this link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap